# sending some data via prepareForSegue issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uistoryboardsegue

I have some issue when doing the segue with some data to to another view.

I have a contact book, first tableview is displaying contacts correctly, also with images
While I click on contact it should perform segue to another tableView. But from some reason it takes only first contact (seems like it's not in a loop).

I have one class for contacts and second ViewController. I can't understand why it happens

I created "pastie" link:

[Here is the link to My code, to save place](http://pastie.org/7997940)

Comment: Can you be more specific, there is no question here, what do you rely want to achieve ?

Comment: @danypata I am trying to send phone numbers on another tableview per contact, but it always sending numbers from the first contact in the list. When I click on second contact in the list (I mean order from top down) it still sending to another controller the same numbers from the first contact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked your code and I think that the problem is when the `prepareForSegue` is called the selected row is already deselected from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. I think that the best approach here is to send the selected index path from didSelectRowAtIndexPath into `performSegue` method something like:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        [self.contTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"NextTable" sender:indexPath];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
      if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"NextTable"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = (NSIndexPath*)sender
        contact = self.contactsToShow[indexPath.row];
        [segue.destinationViewController setPhoneNumbers:contact.numbers];
    }
}
```

In order for this approach to work you must link the segue between view controllers not between cell and table view controller.

Comment: Thanks you it's working perfect for me. But what difference segue from cell and from controller it self? Could you please give a small explanation?

Comment: @Anton You can link cell between cell and destination view controller, in this case, when the cell is tapped the push/modal is done automatically but also the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method is called and since you have the `performSegue` code in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you end up pushing two view controllers, which is not ok. (I'm not sure but I think you have to have static cells in order to link segue to destination vc)

Comment: and user2445981  Thanks Pals :)

Comment: If the segue is triggered directly from the cell, then normally, you don't implement didSelectRowAtIndexPath at all. The sender argument in prepareForSegue:sender: will be the cell you clicked on, so you can get the index path with [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender]. You should also change the type of sender from id to UITableViewCell*

Comment: @rdelmar You are right about not implementing `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` but I didn't know how Anton linked his segues so just to be sure that he will not have problems I mentioned how he should link it and how it shouldn't be linked.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is line 196: You wanna have the index path for the selected row. But because in line 215 you are deselecting the cell immediately after being selected, the index path is always 0.

Comment: Thanks for the quickest answer, I just have commented all method didSelectRowAtIndexPath. But it still the same. I knew that the issue is in segue method, but what I should to add to this IndexPath string?